Are there standardized algorithms for generating list of elements of specified groups?
I ask this question because I have noticed  that both GAP and Mathematica return the same sort-ordering of elements for every specific group I’ve asked them to provide. Do these algorithms have names?
The sort-order of an abelian group is significant in quantum computation vis-a-vis the Fourier transform operator being employed.

Yes, I mean finite groups.

Then, except for cyclic groups, which examples did you take? Can you give a non-trivial example, with such an ordering? The QFT is over an arbitrary cyclic group, there is no problem.

GAP returns a sorted list, with permutations being sorted according to the list of images $[\pi(1),\pi(2),\ldots]$. While I am not privy to knowledge of how Magma operates, this seems a quite plausible explanation why the image lists end up being the same. I would call the ordering lexicographic.
